# What format is required when adding a value to a 'Choice > Allow multiple selections' column in a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-list, power-automate

**Desired Behaviour**

Add Microsoft Form responses to a SharePoint list using this flow:

[Record form responses in SharePoint](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/2be590104bdd11e78896d10a96d3fac3/record-form-responses-in-sharepoint)

**Current Behaviour**

It is working, however the value of a `Multiple Answer, Choice` field is being added to the SharePoint list like this:

`["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]`

rather than this:

`Options 1, Option 2, Option 3`

**What I've Tried**

The column in the *SharePoint list* is of type:

```
Choice  
Allow multiple selections
```

Therefore, I made the corresponding field in the *Microsoft Form* of type:

```
Choice  
Multiple Answers
```

I *can* change the value received from the form like this ([learned from this post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-Submit-Form-to-Sharepoint-List-Multiple-choice-format/m-p/243910)):

[image]

and the value will appear in the SharePoint list as either:

```
Option 1, Option 2, Option 3
```

or:

```
Option 1; Option 2, Option 3
```

However, when trying both of these delimiters (with and without spaces after them `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`), when I `Right Click` > `Edit` on the item in the SharePoint list, the options are *not selected* in the Edit panel on the side of the page.

**Question**

What format is required when adding values to a `Choice > Allow multiple selections` column in a SharePoint list?

Comment: TO DO:  Same question for updating multiple options Lookup column - comment from OP :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the join value this (a semicolon and a hash - `;#`):

[image]

Gleaned from this answer:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/78912

Comment: TO DO:  see if a similar solution is required for adding a date value, or if `dd/mm/yyyy` format will suffice.

Comment: Update:  Indeed it seems some trickery will be required as sending `dd/mm/yyyy` does not add a value to the SharePoint list that forces the calendar widget on the date field to be ‘prepopulated’ with the relevant date when editing the item.